# How do I only show an element if nested ng-repeat is not empty?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a List of lists, created with a nested ng-repeat. Each outer ng-repeat contains a div with the label of its inner list (eg: "Group A"). I'm now trying to create a way to avoid showing this label if the inner list is empty due to filtering(Applied by an input searchtext)

Here is a plunker explaining my issue and my attempted solution : [Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/2rd8rNAUe05N6pFKwKTn?p=preview)

Having a 'heavy' function like isGroupEmpty seems extremely cumbersome - Is there any way to do this in a much simpler fashion? I was toying with the idea of moving the label inside the inner ng-repeat and having `ng-show="$first"` but it doesnt look great

Comment: Can you write it under Plunker/Fiddle?

Comment: create an array of unique groups from persons array. `ng-repeat` over that group array. Then ng-repeat over `person in peopleInGroup(group)`...create scope function  `peopleInGroup(group)` to return filtered result set

Comment: Is there no way to accomplish this without manipulating the model?

Comment: Plunker does seem to display anything?

Comment: there - fixed the link

Comment: Search doesn't seem to be working well in the example!

Comment: Check out [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17514509/1095616).

Comment: Please simplify the Plunk: 1. Toss out this crazy regexp logic.
2. Do not use custom directive if possible. 
3. Make filter actually work (right now it doesn't show whole the list when filter expression is cleared - I think using `$watch`here  is like using a sledgehammer to crack a walnut - try using only custom/build-in filters).

I know it's lot easier to just copy paste code from your project, but Plunks submited on Stackoverflow should be really hello-world-ish - you know... simplest non-working case

Answer (score 60, accepted):

I ended up with the following solution which worked perfectly. [**Plnkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/2rd8rNAUe05N6pFKwKTn?p=preview)

By setting a variable in the inner ng-repeat I was able to evaluate ng-show based on this variables length like so :

```
<input ng-model='searchText'/>
<span ng-show='filtered.length > 0'>
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat='el in filtered = (model | filter:searchText)'>
      <div>{{el.label}}</div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</span>
```

Comment: This is awesome and worked well. Note that you don't need the > 0 in the ng-show.

Comment: I know but I feel like it adds clarity to the solution.

Comment: For others, note that this only works with ng-show, since the element is still rendered and all the scoping works.  If you try with ng-if (preventing the element from rendering), this approach won't work

Answer (score 10):

you could leverage `ng-init`, that way you'll call the filter only once:

```
<div ng-repeat='(key,group) in model'>
  <div ng-init="filtered = (group | filter:filterFn)"></div>
  <div ng-show="filtered.length !== 0">
    <div>{{key}}</div>
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="el in filtered">
        <div>{{el.label}}</div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
 </div>
```

usually it is not a good practice to use `ng-init` out of no where, but I guess it solves calling the filter twice.
Another way is to use the filter through javascript - you could inject $filter and retrieve 'filter' `$filter('filter')` in your controller, calling it with group as its first argument, the filterFn as its second, and store its result in your scope.

Answer (score 3):

I used the following:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="menuItem in menuItems"><a href="Javascript:void(0);"><span class="fa {{menuItem.icon}} fa-lg"></span>{{menuItem.itemName}}</a>
    <span ng-show='menuItem.subItems.length > 0'>
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="subItem in menuItem.subItems"><a href="Javascript:void(0);">{{subItem.itemName}}</a></li>
        </ul>
    </span>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1):

checking if an array has a length of 0 is not an expensive operation. if you want to only show lists that have item, put a filter on the outer array that takes an array of arrays and returns only the arrays that have a length different than 0.

you can also hide the inner div if the array == false.

<strike>http://plnkr.co/edit/gist:3510140</strike>

http://plnkr.co/edit/Gr5uPnRDbRfUYq0ILhmG?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Your plunkr was pretty complicated and hard to weed through so I re-created what you wanted using a fiddle. The general idea behind my approach is to filter out the items from the array, not the sub array. And only do the filtered items when the text changes. So here's the markup:

```
<div ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="ParentCtrl">
        <input data-ng-model="filterText" data-ng-change="updateTypes()" />
        <div data-ng-repeat="type in filteredTypes">
            {{ type.name }}
            <ul>
                <li style="margin-left:20px;" data-ng-repeat="entry in type.entries">
                    - {{ entry.name }}
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here's the code:

```
angular.module('app', [])

function ParentCtrl($scope){
    $scope.filterText = "";
    $scope.types = [
        { name: "type1", entries: [{ name: "name1"}, { name: "name2"}, { name: "name3"}]},
        { name: "type2", entries: [{ name: "name1"}, { name: "name3"}, { name: "name3"}]},
        { name: "type3", entries: [{ name: "name1"}, { name: "name2"}, { name: "name5"}]},
            { name: "type4", entries: [{ name: "name4"}, { name: "name2"}, { name: "name3"}]}
    ];

    $scope.filteredTypes = [];
    $scope.updateTypes = function(){
        $scope.filteredTypes.length = 0;
        for(var x = 0; x < $scope.types.length; x++){
            if($scope.filterText === ""){
                $scope.filteredTypes.push($scope.types[x]);    
            }
            else{
                var entries = [];
                for(var y = 0; y < $scope.types[x].entries.length; y++){
                    if($scope.types[x].entries[y].name.indexOf($scope.filterText) !== -1){
                       entries.push($scope.types[x].entries[y]);   
                    }                        
                }
                if(entries.length > 0){
                    $scope.filteredTypes.push({
                        name: $scope.types[x].name,
                        entries: entries
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    }
    $scope.updateTypes();
}
```

**Fiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/2hRws/

The reason I'm creating a new array and not using an actual filter to remove the results is that angular doesn't like creating dynamic arrays on the fly in filters. This is because it doesn't assign $$hashKey and things just don't line up correctly when dirty checking. I got the idea of how to do what you needed from this topic on the matter: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/angular/IEIQok-YkpU

Answer (score 0):

I have only slightly modified your `list-widget.html`, see it in action: **[plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/pSTkpgYq20fHYMSSuGzq?p=preview)**

The idea is simple - use the same filter for `ng-show`:

```
<div ng-show="group | filter:searchText">{{ key }}</div>
```

The label will be visible only if there are some unfiltered items.

In my example I'm using `searchText` for filter because I'm not familiar with CoffeeScript.