# AngularJS ng-hide in nested dictionary

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-filter, angularjs-ng-show

I have a dictionary like this:

```
var data = {
  a: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
  b: [
    [1, 2],
    [3, 4],
    [5, 6]
  ]
};
```

Now I need to use `ng-hide` to hide an element if `2` exists in `data->a`. It would be done easily like this:

```
<i ng-hide="(data.a | filter:2).length">2 not found</i>
```

Now how I can do it with `data->b`? I need to hide the message if `2` is found in any of `data->b` items.

I found [How do I only show an element if nested ng-repeat is not empty?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20002481/how-do-i-only-show-an-element-if-nested-ng-repeat-is-not-empty). But I need to show to message only once.

Comment: just using `ng-hide="(data.b | filter:2).length"` works for me

Comment: @NewDev Probably ng-show. `I need to show to message only once.` [if not empty] ? confusing.. :/

Comment: @PSL I need to put the code @New Dev suggested inside a loop. As 2 of `b`'s elements doesn't contain `2`, the `2 not found` message will be shown twice. I need to hide the message, only once, if `2` appears in any of `b`'s lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create one filter that will accept array. And it will give you ouput on basis of provided value.

**HTML**

```
<div ng-hide="(data.b | filteronsubarray:2)">2 not found</div>
```

**Filter Code**

```
app.filter('filteronsubarray', function() {
  return function(arr, toFind) {
    var isFound = false;
    angular.forEach(arr, function(val, index) {
      angular.forEach(val, function(v, i) {
        if(v == toFind){
          isFound = true;
        }
      });
    });
    return isFound;
  }
});
```

Here is Fiddle link(http://plnkr.co/edit/gApW4sAYMOBLPh8gJyE3?p=preview)

Hope this is helpful to you.

Comment: Mark the answer if it is helpful to you.

Comment: PS. I will mark it as the correct answer. Be patient!!

Answer (score 0):

If all you need is to do whatever you did for `data.a`, except for each element of `data.b`, then you just need to iterate over `data.b` and apply the same logic:

```
<i ng-repeat="b in data.b"
   ng-hide="(b | filter:2).length">2 not found</i>
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/QnGYaMQvAkNr7YH35D7J?p=preview)