# How do I count object keys to determine an expression?

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to hide the parent element of a table (with rows created using ng-repeat) if the table is empty. I've found the follow example:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/14616397/930998

But that only applies to arrays. I have an object with nested objects like this:

```
{
  "-J9dKgyHpCTNNImuydo6" : {
    "url" : "http://www.example.se",
    "title" : "Example 1",
    "uuid" : "-J9dKgyHpCTNNImuydo6",
    "sla" : false
  },
  "-J9dKQ2kxHzFc5-bJIKN" : {
    "url" : "http://www.example.com",
    "title" : "Example 2",
    "uuid" : "-J9dKQ2kxHzFc5-bJIKN",
    "sla" : true
  }
}
```

My repeater looks like this:

```
  <tr ng-repeat="site in sites | archived:false">
    <td class="title">{{site.title}}</td>
    <td class="url"><a href="{{site.url}}" target="_blank">{{site.url}}</a></td>
    <td class="sla">{{site.sla | BooleanToText}}</td>
  </tr>
```

As you can see I have a filter on the repeater as well. What I'm trying to do is hide the whole table if "site in sites | archived:false" is empty. I've tried the following:

```
ng-show="(sites | archived:false).length"
```

and

```
ng-show="(Object.keys(sites) | archived:false).length"
```

But I can't get it right. I think the length always returns 0 no matter what I do.

Here's a fiddle to make it more visible: http://jsfiddle.net/insats/djD4m/3/
I basically want to hide the wrapping div if the table is empty.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Filtering an ng-repeat list based on a sub-object property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17514272/filtering-an-ng-repeat-list-based-on-a-sub-object-property)

Comment: You might be right, but that answer didn't help me either :/

I added a js fiddle for clarity: http://jsfiddle.net/insats/djD4m/3/

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "didn't help me" but here's a fork of your fiddle where table is hidden exactly as described in that duplicate question: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LwSFW/).

Comment: What I mean is that using .length didn't work for me, it was undefined. I think it has to do with my filter returning an object on which you can't use .length. I couldn't figure out how to solve it. Anyway, the fiddle you linked to just now looks like the one I posted, was it the wrong url?

Comment: I did not notice you are iterating over object. In that case you might still use my approach but it requires minor adjustment to your custom filter. [Correct fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/6Kd4z/1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe there is an easier solution but for sure this will work:

Add a method that indicates if the filtered collection is empty:

```
$scope.isNonArchivedSiteCollectionEmpty = function () {
... // you can use filter here or some simpler logic to determine if there is
... // at least one element in the collection
}
```

Then in your view just use:

```
ng-hide="isNonArchivedSiteCollectionEmpty()"
```

**UPDATE** Probably the most reasonable way is just to keep and refresh filter collection from the `$scope` and resign using filter in the markup altogether. Then you could very easily check if it is empty or not.

Comment: You're right, but that's what I want to use my filter to do. The new method would basically do the same thing

Comment: @AdamGerthel it could be simpler than filter -- as you just have to check if at least one element has `archived:false`.

Comment: hmm, that's true. Say that my list contains 1000 objects. Would using a new method demand less computing? I.e. would the filter have to run twice if I used that as the expression to determine true/false? btw I added a fiddle to my op.

Comment: @AdamGerthel updated my answer. In worst case, in big-O terms it would be the same in practice much faster, since you do not have to create new collection and you do not have to copy any references and you can stop immediately after having found single occurrence of `archived:false` -- which if `true` and `false` are distributed uniformly, means than *on average* you just check 2 elements.

Comment: I got it working using two methods. One that returns true if there are archived sites (used with ng-show on the archived table) and another doing the opposite.

See my updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/insats/NkZSL/1/

I'm sure it can be improved codewise. Thanks for the help though!